# Transfer charge from a battery to another battery storage

Tags: lipo, charge

I am conducting a feasibility study and one of the features of our innovation is that the "charge" that has been stored in our "Li-Po battery" can be transfer to another "battery storage"

I would like to know if this transferring process is possible through a cable wire connected to both Li-Po and the another battery storage.
(If not, what are the ways on how to transfer this charge)
I would also like to know if we are also using Li-Po battery as our second "battery  storage"

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: How much of the stored charge are you trying to transfer?

Comment: Our lipo battery have 1300mAh charge capaticity.

Comment: How much of the stored charge are you trying to transfer?

Comment: How is this different from a [power bank](https://www.amazon.com/power-bank/s?k=power+bank)?

Answer (score 1):

Make a buck-boost converter that draws power from the one battery. Then make a charge circuit that can charge the other battery. Spec it so that the input of one is the same as the output of the other. Combine the two and you can transfer charge from one to the other.

You could probably make a buck-boost converter with an efficiency around 97 percent. You will also have loss in the charging circuit i'm not sure how efficient this could be.

This will in reality be a battery bank, that instead of charging your phones battery, charges another battery.

With the popper protection and isolation it will also be possible to connect them in parallel or in series. This is effectively what is done in multi-cell LiPo battery packs.